# Trying to Update ssh key to existing user in azure linux vm whcih has been created using SSH Key Service via Azure portal

Tags: azure, powershell, ssh, azure-cli

I am trying to use Add-AzVMSshPublicKey cmdlet to update ssh key on existing Azure linux VM , command executed without an issue but key hasnt been updated on server.
Is there any other way available where i can able to achieve OR any Azure cli command to do same ?

Answer (score 0):

The [Add-AzVMSshPublicKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/add-azvmsshpublickey?view=azps-6.0.0) cmdlet is used to add the public keys for SSH for a virtual machine, **when only creating the VM**. If you use the command with Update-AzVM, the command will error. So it does not use to add the keys after VM is created.

The following example updates the SSH key for the user `azureuser` on the VM named `myVM`.

```
az vm user update \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name myVM \
  --username azureuser \
  --ssh-key-value ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

You can use the above CLI commands to append the new public key text to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file for the admin user on the VM. This does not replace or remove any existing SSH keys. You can SSH into that VM to remove the old public key if you would like to remove it.

Read [Manage administrative users, SSH, and check or repair disks on Linux VMs using the VMAccess Extension with the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/vmaccess#update-ssh-key) for more details.

Alternatively, you can reset the SSH key from the Azure portal---> reset password.

[image]

Comment: Hey Nancy,  Thx 4 ur response but az vm update  cli command giving me an error , i have to copy ssh key over 1k VM's .